# How does a synchronized pool allocator (re)use a monotonic one?

Tags: c++

In the example below

```cpp
// allocate chunks of memory (starting with 10k) without deallocating:
std::pmr::monotonic_buffer_resource monotonic{10'000};


for (int j=0; j < 100; ++j) {
    std::pmr::synchronized_pool_resource pool{&monotonic};

    std::pmr::vector<std::pmr::string> coll{&pool};
    for (int i=0; i < 100; ++i) {
        coll.emplace_back("123");
    }
}
```

is the pool supposed to be re-using memory from the monotinic allocator in every loop iteration? According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77330902/4224575) such a thing should be possible, but how does the synchronized pool resource achieve it?

I'm mostly concerned with how this is possible since the monotonic resource is inherently "non reusable", i.e. unless it's destroyed it doesn't give back its memory.

## EDIT:

I guess I was reading my sources wrong. According to an [**experiment**](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/362b52b7c97a80de) prompted by @Homer512's answer the synchronized pool must be out of the loop and the secret sauce lies in the destructor of vector:

```cpp
    std::pmr::monotonic_buffer_resource monotonic{1'024};
    std::pmr::synchronized_pool_resource pool{&monotonic};

    for (int j=0; j < 3; ++j) {    
        std::pmr::vector<std::pmr::string> coll{&pool};
        coll.emplace_back("123");
        std::cout << "Allocated at: " << coll.data() << "\n";
    }
```

prints:

```
Allocated at: 0x18e0680
Allocated at: 0x18e0680
Allocated at: 0x18e0680
```

which will have an effect equivalent to calling `poll.deallocate(ptr, N);` as in the linked answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key difference between your code and the one in the cited answer is that your code creates a new pool in every iteration of the outer loop. That does not work.

The `synchronized_pool_resource` does reuse its own allocations. So if you destroy the `vector`, its memory will go back to the pool and a new vector can be created with the same memory from the same pool. When the pool runs out of cached memory allocations, it requests more from the `monotonic_buffer_resource` which it can then reuse as long as the pool exists.

The problem is that you destroy the pool. The pool will release all its memory to the `monotonic_buffer_resource` but the buffer handles a [`do_deallocate` method](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/monotonic_buffer_resource/do_deallocate) call as a no-op. It will not reuse the memory. The next pool will request new memory from the buffer and it will get more, freshly allocated memory. Only when the buffer is destroyed will its memory be released.

Keep both objects in the same lifetime scope and you are fine.

Also, one more warning: The [`largest_required_pool_block`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/pool_options) setting means that the pool will ask the buffer directly for memory above a certain threshold and in return will release it directly to that buffer. Do not use that option with a monotonic buffer as the upstream resource of the pool since it will fail to properly deallocate the directly allocated memory in the same way. And as the linked page notes:

> If `largest_required_pool_block` is zero or is greater than an implementation-defined limit, that limit is used instead

So … yeah. Don't use this setup with allocations that may have an unbound upper size (vectors, strings) or you may not be able to reuse allocated memory. And the standard gives you no way to know when this happens. You can always use a pool with the `new_delete_resource` as its upstream resource instead if that is a concern.

Comment: that option with the monotinic buffer is used in an example at "C++17 the complete guide" by Nico Josuttis. the intent is to "create a pool for all of our memory, which never deallocates as long as it lives and is initialized by starting to allocate 10,000 bytes". Also on each iteration of the loop, the vector "dies", so it's supposed to give back the memory to the pool (the comment says "deallocations are given back to pool, but not deallocated" so that's what prompted me to assume that the next iteration will start from "scratch" with monotonic

Comment: ok checks out, I've posted an experiment with what you say. What you wrote about the "largest_required_pool_block" is not correct though. I'm just using the [constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/monotonic_buffer_resource/monotonic_buffer_resource) of monotonic buffer that accepts a `size_t` parameter which is "the minimum size of the first buffer to allocate; must be greater than zero". Monotonic buffer has no constructor that accepts `pool_options`

Comment: @LorahAttkins The `pool_options` goes to the [`synchronized_pool_resource` constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/synchronized_pool_resource/synchronized_pool_resource).

Comment: @LorahAttkins Ah, I see where the confusion came from. I meant "Do not use that option with a monotonic buffer *as the upstream resource for the pool* for the same reason"