Issue using unsynchronized_pool_resource for a pmr::vector allocation
Following up a similar question some months ago <[combination of monotonic buffer and unsynchronized memory pool]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77271609/c17-combination-of-monotonic-buffer-and-unsynchronized-memory-pool>,  I am trying to combine monotonic buffer and unsynchronized pool resource to efficiently allocate memory without got to heap for memory allocation.
#include <iostream>
#include <memory_resource>
#include <vector>
class A{
    char array[64];
};
typename std::aligned_storage<32000>::type storage;
thread_local std::pmr::monotonic_buffer_resource bufferPool{&storage,sizeof(storage),std::pmr::null_memory_resource()};
std::pmr::unsynchronized_pool_resource pool{{},&bufferPool};

int main()
{

    for(int i =0; i < 10000;++i){
    
        
        std::pmr::vector<A> vec (&pool);
        vec.reserve(1000);
        for(int j =0; j < 1000;++j){
            vec.emplace_back();
        }
    }
}

Based on the previous answer the expectation the memory block to return in pool and reuse for next allocation. But this does not happen. In next allocations go again to monotonic buffer which behaves monotonically and after some iterations memory runs out
What am I missing?
And why the below example works and reuse the same memory in each iteration?
#include <iostream>
#include <memory_resource>

int main() {
    char buffer[1024];
    std::pmr::monotonic_buffer_resource monotonicResource(buffer, sizeof(buffer));

    // Use an unsynchronized_pool_resource on top of the monotonic_buffer_resource
    std::pmr::unsynchronized_pool_resource poolResource(&monotonicResource);

    // Allocate and deallocate memory using the unsynchronized_pool_resource
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
        std::cout << "Iteration " << i << ":\n";

        // Allocate memory
        void* ptr = poolResource.allocate(200);  // request 200 bytes from the pool
        std::cout << "Allocated at: " << ptr << "\n";

        // Deallocate memory (returning it to the pool! Not the monotonic resource)
        poolResource.deallocate(ptr, 200);

        std::cout << "Deallocated.\n\n";
    }

    return 0;
}

What is the difference between them?

The pool allocator implementations typically have 2 optimizations that make it optimized for many small allocations but very bad for large allocations.

it rounds up allocation to the next power of 2, allocating 1025 bytes means you allocate 2048 bytes.
it allocates N blocks of that size at a time, where N is 8 on MSVC by default, this is controlled through pool_options, so in the above example if you ask for 1025 bytes it allocates at least 16 KB, it also allocates extra memory for tracking and management, so throw in an extra 2 KB as an error margin .... so a simple 1KB allocation becomes an 18 KB allocation, this is exaggerated but not unrealistic.

The allocator works, But in order to allocate 64 KB of memory on MSVC it is requesting close to 720 KB of memory which the small 32 KB buffer cannot satisfy.
The solution is really simple, Don't use it for large vectors, you can re-use the vector memory without using a pmr::allocator, just put it outside of the for loop, or a part of the class.
std::vector<A> vec;
vec.reserve(1000);
for (int i = 0; i < 10000; ++i) {
    vec.clear();
    for (int j = 0; j < 1000; ++j) {
        vec.emplace_back();
    }
}

Those pmr allocators are more useful for smaller allocations like map or unordered_map or list where each time you allocate small nodes of constant size, it is also useful for small vectors, closer to 10 elements.
If you still want to use it for a large vector, you want to set the max_blocks_per_chunk in pool_options to 1 and you want to let the allocator draw memory from the unlimited global heap, because you cannot know in advance how much memory it is going to need.
Also gcc/clang have a 4 MB / 1 MB largest_required_pool_block by default, so you need to specify that you need larger allocations in pool_options if you need bigger allocations.
std::pmr::monotonic_buffer_resource bufferPool{};
std::pmr::unsynchronized_pool_resource pool{std::pmr::pool_options{1,1024*1024*1024},&bufferPool};

Even after setting it to only allocate 1 block per chunk, it is allocating 140 KB to satisfy the 64 KB allocation, don't try to estimate the memory you will need in advance, you can allocate a small buffer on the stack to handle small allocations for small vectors (like 10 KB), but you must allow it to fall-back to the global heap for large vectors.

Modified code https://godbolt.org/z/83We9zd6Y. In each loop the same addresses are used apart from the two last elemets. Why does it happen. Seems that works only for 10 elements and monotonic buffer size is 4K. Huge memory waste. @Ahmend AEK

@getsoubl you need to increase the largest_required_pool_block as its default on gcc is 4 MB, and you need a much bigger buffer for larger allocations, as i said in the answer, it is wasteful because it is optimized for small allocations, not large allocations
https://godbolt.org/z/rsr85v88n

@getsoubl largest_required_pool_block needs to be bigger than the entire vector block, ie: a vector of 1000 elements will need an 8 KB block, so largest_required_pool_block needs to be larger than 8 KB ... but vector capacity is not going to be exactly 1000 because its capacity doubles each time it grows, so you likely need largest_required_pool_block to be at least 16 KB

@Ahmend AEK, why largest_required_pool_block needs to be bigger than entire vector?Do not each block per chunk contains one element of vector? My expectation is that 64 bytes per block should be ok. https://godbolt.org/z/e1r9Tdc4d. What am I missing? I reduce the allocation to 10. In the latest example no address of monotonic buffer is reused

@getsoubl the allocator sees the entire vector as 1 single block, (because the vector MUST be contiguous, unlike list or map, which can be fragmented) , the vector requests from the allocator a single block of size(A) * number_of_elements, the allocator thinks you are allocating one single large object of that size.
